# Postman Pre-request Script does not exclude fields

Tags: elasticsearch, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am trying to exclude fields from response that is returned from elasticsearch using postman pre-request script but looks like exclude is not working as expected. Below is my pre-request script -

```
pm.sendRequest({
        url: 'https://' + pm.globals.get("creds") + pm.globals.get("server") + ':9200/' + pm.globals.get("details") + '/_read',
        method: 'POST',
        header: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: {
            mode: 'raw',
            raw: JSON.stringify({

    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "id":pm.environment.get("id")
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": {
          "exclude" : ["demographic.*"]
     }
}
            )
        }
    }
);
```

I have already tested this query in elastic search and it is working as expected. I would appreciate any help

Comment: Hey Jon, can you provide some more context please. This looks like a request inside and main request, where are you hoping to see the output of this?

Comment: @DannyDainton i am hoping to see this output in postman i.e. response body. So the postman pre-request script is used prior to the request that is being sent to API. In this case i am trying to send a pre-request to elastic-search with query and then i want to perform assertion over the response but my concern is that this query is not working in postman as expected. It should exclude the demographics array from the response but it is not

Comment: Actually never mind i was able to check in console that my query is working as expected.

Comment: You're only ever going to see the output from a `.sendRequest` in the Postman Console. Unless the request is the main request in the builder, you're not going to see that in the response body section.

Comment: yes thank you for clarifying this to me. I should have known that pre-requests are meant for postman console not for API response